# jquery:simple pagination solution needed

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this code i cannt complete;

```
<div class=paginatme></div>
<div class=paginatme></div>
<div class=paginatme></div>
<div class=paginatme></div>
<div class=paginatme></div>
<div class=paginatme></div>
<div class=paginatme></div>
<div class=paginatme></div>
<div class=paginatme></div>
<input type=hidden value=1 id=current_shown onchange='functioN(this.value)'>
<a href=''>Next</a><a href=''>previous</a>
<script>
 functionN(x){
 ///CODE THAT SHOW div number X and 2 after and hide all..
 }
</script>
```

i want to to add style=display:none to all and show them 3 by 3 on ahref click.

how can i count elements and give them style and none to rest ??

Comment: I just leave a block of "n" and rotate through according to which page I'm on, assigning values to the existing ones. that can be done in either javascript or server languages. I can link you to such an example if you like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
functionN(x){
  $(".paginatme").hide();
  $(".paginatme:eq("+x+")").show();
  if (x == 8) x = -1;
  x++;
  $("#current_shown").val(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use .toggle() to switch on\off visibility of objects